# Terraform - how to use for_each loop on a list of objects to create resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, foreach, terraform

I have an object containing the list of subnets I want to create.

```
variable "subnet-map" {
  default = {
    ec2 = [
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
      }
    ],
    lambda = [
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.5.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.6.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.7.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1c"
      }
    ],
    secrets = [
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.8.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.9.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.10.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1c"
      }
    ],
    rds = [
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.11.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.12.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
      },
      {
        cidr_block        = "10.0.13.0/24"
        availability_zone = "eu-west-1c"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Earlier I was using the count loop construct. So I used to flatten the above structure into a list of objects

```
locals {
  subnets = flatten([
    for resource in keys(var.subnet-map) : [
      for subnet in var.subnet-map[resource] : {
        resource          = resource
        cidr_block        = subnet.cidr_block
        availability_zone = subnet.availability_zone
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

And then I would create the resources by doing

```
resource "aws_subnet" "aws-subnets" {
  count             = length(local.subnets)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.aws-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = local.subnets[count.index].cidr_block
  availability_zone = local.subnets[count.index].availability_zone

  tags = {
    Name = "subnet-${local.subnets[count.index].resource}-${local.subnets[count.index].availability_zone}"
  }
}
```

Now I want to use the for_each loop. But I cannot figure out how to do it. This is what I've done so far.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets-dev" {
  for_each          = var.subnet-map
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc-dev.id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr_block
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone

  tags = {
    Name        = "subnet-dev-${each.value.resource}-${each.value.availability_zone}"
    environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

But it keeps giving an error saying

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on vpc/main.tf line 93, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnets-dev":
  93:     Name        = "subnet-dev-${each.value.resource}-${each.value.availability_zone}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is tuple with 3 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Based on the error message and the structure you show at the beginning of the question, it appears you are attempting to access values from a tuple of maps, which will not work. You would need to iterate over your tuple of maps to access specific values from those maps.

Comment: Right. But how? Could you give me a brief example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully follow all of what you tried here because your initial snippet of `var.subnet-map` shows it being a map of maps of lists of objects, but later on when you used `for_each = var.subnet-map` it seems to have treated it as a map of lists instead. Did you remove that extra level of maps (the "default" key) before trying `for_each` here?

Working with your original definition of `variable "subnet-map"`, your first step with `for_each` will be similar to what you did with `count`: you need to flatten the structure, this time into a map of objects rather than a list of objects. The easiest way to get there is to derive a map from your existing flattened list:

```
locals {
  subnets = flatten([
    for resource in keys(var.subnet-map) : [
      for subnet in var.subnet-map[resource] : {
        resource          = resource
        cidr_block        = subnet.cidr_block
        availability_zone = subnet.availability_zone
      }
    ]
  ])

  subnets_map = {
    for s in local.subnets: "${s.resource}:${s.availability_zone}" => s
  }
}
```

Here I assumed that your "resource" string and your availability zone together are a suitable unique identifier for a subnet. If not, you can adjust the `"${s.resource}:${s.availability_zone}"` part to whatever unique key you want to use for these.

Now you can use the flattened map as the `for_each` map:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets-dev" {
  for_each          = local.subnets_map
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc-dev.id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr_block
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone

  tags = {
    Name        = "subnet-dev-${each.value.resource}-${each.value.availability_zone}"
    environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

This will give you instances with addresses like `aws_subnet.subnets-dev["ec2:eu-west-1a"]`.

---

Note that if you are migrating from `count` with existing subnets that you wish to retain, you'll need to also do a one-time migration step to tell Terraform which indexes from the existing state correspond to which keys in the new configuration.

For example, if (and only if) index `0` was previously the one for `ec2` in `eu-west-1a`, the migration command for that one would be:

```
terraform state mv 'aws_subnet.subnets-dev[0]' 'aws_subnet.subnets-dev["ec2:eu-west-1a"]'
```

If you're not sure how they correlate, you can run `terraform plan` after adding `for_each` and look at the instances that Terraform is planning to destroy. If you work through each one of those in turn, taking the address Terraform currently knows along with the resource and availability zone names shown in the `Name` tag, you can migrate each of them to its new address so that Terraform will no longer think you're asking for it to destroy the numbered instances and replace them with named ones.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. No I didn't remove the extra layer of maps. It's exactly the same as before. I just don't know how to use it correctly with a `for_each` loop. Creating the second map sounds clever. I would try it tomorrow. Also, it's not a migration.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now that I have subnets like - `aws_subnet.subnets-dev["ec2:eu-west-1a"]`... is there any way to select only the RDS subnets (all three), or only the EC2 subnets (here, only 1)?