# How to loop through locals and list at the same time to generate resources

Tags: terraform

I have the following tf file:

```
locals {
  schemas = {
    "ODS" = {
      usage_roles = ["TRANSFORMER"]
    }
    "EXT" = {
      usage_roles = []
    }
    "INT" = {
      usage_roles = ["REPORTER"]
    }
    "DW" = {
      usage_roles = ["LOADER"]
    }
  }
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "schema" {
  for_each = local.schemas
  name = each.key
  database = ???????
  usage_roles = each.value.usage_roles
}
```

I want to maintain the locals as it is (different usage_roles for each schema and hardcoded here) while having several values as database for each schema. In pseudo-code it would be:

```
for database in ['db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3']:
    resource "snowflake_schema" "schema" {
      for_each = local.schemas
      name = each.key
      database = database
      usage_roles = each.value.usage_roles
    }
```

So that we have the same schema resource in the three different databases. I have read some articles that point me to the belief that it is possible to make this loop but pre assigning all the values, meaning that I would have to put usage_roles in a list or something instead of hardcoding here in locals, which I think is less readable. For instance:
[Terraform - how to use for_each loop on a list of objects to create resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570505/terraform-how-to-use-for-each-loop-on-a-list-of-objects-to-create-resources)

Is even possible what I am asking for? If so, how? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main requirement for `for_each` is that the map you provide must have one element per instance of the resource you want to create. In your case, I think that means you need a map with one element per every combination of database and schema.

The operation of finding every combination of values in two sets is formally known as the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), and Terraform has [the `setproduct` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html) to perform that operation. In your case, the two sets to apply it to are the set of database names and the set of keys in your schemas map, like this:

```
locals {
  databases = toset(["db_1", "db_2", "db_3"])

  database_schemas = [
    for pair in setproduct(local.databases, keys(local.schemas)) : {
      database_name = pair[0]
      schema_name   = pair[1]
      usage_roles   = local.schemas[pair[1]].usage_roles
    }
  ]
}
```

The `local.database_schemas` value would then contain an object for each combination, like this:

```
[
  {
    database_name = "db_1"
    schema_name   = "ODS"
    usage_roles   = ["TRANSFORMER"]
  },
  {
    database_name = "db_1"
    schema_name   = "EXT"
    usage_roles   = []
  },
  # ...
  {
    database_name = "db_2"
    schema_name   = "ODS"
    usage_roles   = ["TRANSFORMER"]
  },
  {
    database_name = "db_2"
    schema_name   = "EXT"
    usage_roles   = []
  },
  # ...
  {
    database_name = "db_3"
    schema_name   = "ODS"
    usage_roles   = ["TRANSFORMER"]
  },
  {
    database_name = "db_3"
    schema_name   = "EXT"
    usage_roles   = []
  },
  # ...
]
```

This meets the requirement of having one element per instance you want to create, but we still need to convert it to a map with a unique key per element to give Terraform a unique tracking key for each instance, so we can do one more `for` projection in the `for_each` argument:

```
resource "snowflake_schema" "schema" {
  for_each = {
    for s in local.database_schemas :
    "${s.database_name}:${s.schema_name}" => s
  }

  name        = each.value.schema_name
  database    = each.value.database_name
  usage_roles = each.value.usage_roles
}
```

Terraform will track these instances with addresses like this:

- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_1:ODS"]`
- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_1:EXT"]`
- ...
- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_2:ODS"]`
- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_2:EXT"]`
- ...
- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_3:ODS"]`
- `snowflake_schema.schema["db_3:EXT"]`
- ...